# Creating json from two bash arrays

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I have two bash arrays:

```bash
arr1="200 300 400"
arr2=(1000 10001 10002)
```

I would like to produce a `json` file with a bash script:

```json
{
  "200": {"feature1": 1000},
  "300": {"feature1": 1001},
  "400": {"feature1": 1002}
}
```

I tried doing it with `jq`:

```bash
jq -n --arg arg1 "${arr1[*]}" \
      --arg arg2 "${arr2[*]}" \
      '{$arg1: {"feature1": $arg2}}'
```

but this only expands the whole arrays into one entry.

[EDIT]: What if I have the third array with file paths and would like to place them as feature 2:

```json
{
  "200": {
    "feature1": 1000,
    "feature2": "path-to-files/1000.log"
  },
  "300": {
    "feature1": 1001,
    "feature2": "path-to-files/1001.log"
  },
  "400": {
    "feature1": 1002,
    "feature2": "path-to-files/1002.log"
  }
}
```

[EDIT2]: My workflow:

```bash
arr1="200 300 400"
arr2=()
arr3=()
arr2_content=1000
for i in $arr1; do
    arr2+=("$arr2_content")
    touch "$arr2_content.log"
    arr3+=("$PWD/$arr2_content.log")
    arr2_content=$((arr2_content+1))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Only `arr2` is an array. `arr1` is just a string containing spaces. Therefore you can read in `arr1` using the `--arg` option, and `/ " "` to split it at the spaces, and use the `--args` option for the "real" array `arr2`:

```bash
jq -n --arg arg "$arr1" '[$arg / " ", $ARGS.positional]
  | reduce transpose[] as [$key, $feature1] ({}; .[$key] = {$feature1})
' --args "${arr2[@]}"
```

```json
{
  "200": {
    "feature1": "1000"
  },
  "300": {
    "feature1": "10001"
  },
  "400": {
    "feature1": "10002"
  }
}
```

---

To make the conversion to numbers in the values, use `tonumber`:

```bash
jq -n --arg arg "$arr1" '[$arg / " ", $ARGS.positional]
  | reduce transpose[] as [$key, $val] ({}; .[$key] = {feature1: $val | tonumber})
' --args "${arr2[@]}"
```

```json
{
  "200": {
    "feature1": 1000
  },
  "300": {
    "feature1": 10001
  },
  "400": {
    "feature1": 10002
  }
}
```

---

### Generalizing to:

### How can I import two (or more) indexed bash arrays into jq

This is less trivial because the trick of using `--args` (populating the argument stack with the array items) can only be used once. Or more precisely: `--args` simply passes all remaining arguments to the internal `$ARGS` object, so even if you pass on both arrays, the items will arrive but the information where the first one ends and the second one starts will be lost. Here are a few workarounds:

##### Using a separator item

You could sneak in a special item between the two arrays, so that by spotting its index from within jq the arrays can be recovered by slicing around that item. The caveat here is that this separator item must be unique(ly identifiable), otherwise the splitting may occur anywhere across the arrays. Also finding such an item may or may not be easy, depending on the type of data stored in the arrays. Let's assume the empty string `""` is such a value that never occurs as item in any of the arrays. Then you may go with something along the lines of:

```bash
keys="200 300 400"
arr1=("one" "two" "two and a half")
arr2=("three and four" "five" "six")
sep=""
init=1000
jq -n --arg keys "$keys" --arg sep "$sep" --argjson init "$init" '
  [$keys / " ", ($ARGS.positional | index($sep) as $i | .[:$i], .[$i+1:])]
  | . + [[$init + range(first | length)]]
  | reduce transpose[] as [$key, $feature1, $feature2, $counter] ({};
      .[$key] = {$counter, $feature1, $feature2}
    )
' --args "${arr1[@]}" "" "${arr2[@]}"    # note the special item
```

##### Providing array lengths

Instead of determining the index to split at based on the argument array itself, you could provide that information separately, as it is already available in the Bash context. For the use-case at hand, the arrays are believed to have equal lengths, so instead of repeating the indexing from above (which would work too), I will use `_nwise` which produces slices of equal lengths:

```bash
keys="200 300 400"
arr1=("one" "two" "two and a half")
arr2=("three and four" "five" "six")
len=${#arr1}    # note the dynamic computation of the length
init=1000
jq -n --arg keys "$keys" --argjson len "$len" --argjson init "$init" '
  [$keys / " ", ($ARGS.positional | _nwise($len))]
  | . + [[$init + range(first | length)]]
  | reduce transpose[] as [$key, $feature1, $feature2, $counter] ({};
      .[$key] = {$counter, $feature1, $feature2}
    )
' --args "${arr1[@]}" "${arr2[@]}"    # just the two arrays
```

##### Preprocessing the arrays

A completely different approach could be to invoke separate instances of jq just to convert the bash arrays into JSON arrays (one call per array - the `--args` option can be used here as shown above). This is practical, as jq offers more possibilities to read in JSON arrays (after all it's a JSON processor). However, keep in mind that performacewise this can become expensive, especially when loops and iterations are involved. But If there is only a single run with two arrays, the difference between calling jq once and doing it three times will hardly be noticeable. To import the JSON array, using options like `--argjson` for inline data (as seen in the last approach), or `--argfile` and `--slurpfile` for referenced data (using [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) `<()` here is quite common) would be one way. As this use-case has no (other) external input (we were using the `-n` option all the time), the converted arrays can also be streamed in via the "main enterance". Using `-s` instead also can take care of collecting the stream into a big array (which is the counterpart of what happened in the first line of the previous approaches):

```bash
keys="200 300 400"
arr1=("one" "two" "two and a half")
arr2=("three and four" "five" "six")
init=1000
{
  jq -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${arr1[@]}"
  jq -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${arr2[@]}"
} |
jq -s --arg keys "$keys" --argjson init "$init" '    # no other parameters here
  [$keys / " "] + . + [[$init + range(first | length)]]
  | reduce transpose[] as [$key, $feature1, $feature2, $counter] ({};
      .[$key] = {$counter, $feature1, $feature2}
    )
'
```

##### Output

All these approaches produce the same output:

```json
{
  "200": {
    "counter": 1000,
    "feature1": "one",
    "feature2": "three and four"
  },
  "300": {
    "counter": 1001,
    "feature1": "two",
    "feature2": "five"
  },
  "400": {
    "counter": 1002,
    "feature1": "two and a half",
    "feature2": "six"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Since you were so quick, can you please check the edited question with two features, three arrays?

Comment: @gasar8 If the "third array" is actually a string (like the first one), just follow that, i.e. use another `--arg` option, split at the spaces (or a different string if you prefer), place it in the initial array for transpositon, and add another field `feature2` to set it. But if there are at least two real arrays, i.e. the "third one" is like the second one, more trickery is needed, as you can use `--args` only once. For instance, you could place a delimiter item between the two arrays, then recover them by spotting it in the positional array. Please give an example to make this answerable.

Comment: Yes, I think this was actually my initial question since I thought that the first one is also an array - how to take into account two "real arrays". The third one is a real array containing file paths. I actually loop through `arr1`, assign it an incremental number which I append to `arr2` and simultaneously create a file whose filepath I add to `arr3`. Will modify the question.

Comment: @gasar8 Sorry I've got to go now, but here's the concept I was talking about with a delimiter item (which must be unique, say `""`): Try this as example: `a1=(a b c); a2=(d e f);  jq -n '$ARGS.positional | index("") as $i | [.[:$i], .[$i+1:]]' --args "${a1[@]}" "" "${a2[@]}"`. Another alternative could be to use separate `jq` calls to preconvert the bash arrays into JSON arrays, and then read them in as JSON using the `--argjson` option. I'm sure somebody will chime in to explicate. If not, I will do it as soon as I come back. Good luck!